# Adding autoprefixer script to react-create-app project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json

I'm trying to add a postcss [autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer) script to my project, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this with my current setup - without `webpack`, `grunt` or `gulp`. This is my script configuration in **package.json**:

```
"start": "npm-run-all -p watch-sass start-js",
"start-js": "react-scripts start",
"build": "npm-run-all -s sass build-js",
"build-js": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"sass": "node-sass --output-style compressed -o src/style src/style",
"watch-sass": "npm run sass && node-sass -o src/style src/style --watch --recursive"
```

I'd like to add a `postcss` script that adds prefixes to my compiled css files and outputs them in the same directory

Edit: I would also like the script to watch for changes, just like the node-sass script does

Comment: I've been looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you created your react app via create-react-app script then it comes auto included: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/post-processing-css/